# Android auto GPS on/off code not working with Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: android, gps

I am using code to Auto GPS on/off this code is working fine with Karbonn handset but not on Samsung Galaxy Y.

```
public void turnGPSOn() {
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
        // if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);

    }
}


public void turnGPSOff() {

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps")) {
        // if gps is enabled
        final Intent gps = new Intent();
        gps.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        gps.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        gps.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(gps);

    }
}
```

By using turnGPSOff method Samsung device does not make any change. turnGPSOn methods works well. But turnGPSOn method have a problem, by using this method after getting the fix GPS receiver does not go on sleep mode, it always blink on mobile screen. When i do not use this method then after getting fix GPS receiver go on sleep mode till next frequency value.
Any idea? Please help.

Comment: You should not be turning GPS on or off without user consent. Please direct users to Settings UI if the GPS is off and ask them to turn it on.

Comment: yeah that i know, but i need to do this. Same code working with karbonn,htc but why not with samsung?

Comment: Because there is no standard/public API for what you are trying to accomplish. Your current code may break anytime even with HTC....